# Smoothly connect two objects (Cylinder+Plane)

Tags: modeling

I have the below hexagonal shape with a 45 degree extruding pipe. I would like to connect the edges of the hexagon to the outer side of the pipe's top rim all around. It should be a smooth, curved connection as if the pipe is pushing up a flexible cloth.

[image]

Thanks a bunch for your help.

Comment: Do you actually want something that looks like cloth to span the edge loops(with things like creases and folds), or do you just need a way to create a face between the pipe and the hexagon(not necessarily cloth-like)?

Comment: The latter, it should just connect the pipe and hexagon. No creases and folds are desired. I had planned to increase the cloth tension to remove any of those (if I had gotten it to work in the first place ;-) )

Comment: Right, l added an answer. Excuse me the weird formatting; mobile does not seem to have a post preview option; takes some trial and error to get that right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### TOPOLOGY

It's always better to work with simple topology, so you don't fall into a troubles with next step in modelling. So I would recommend ...

- ad *Cylinder* 6 sides and *Cylinder* 12 sides, position them and use *Boolean Modifier* > *Union*

[image]
[image]

- to get a same amount of vertices, select loop of hexagon, Subdivide (W) it, select both parts of top surface and delete them, select both loops and search for *Bridge*

[image]
[image: a]

### version BEVEL

- now you can select loop to Bevel (cmd+B), under Adjust last operation (F9) choose **Percentage** and set **100%**

[image]
[image]

### version BRIDGE

- instead of beveling you can select subdivided hexagon edge directly and circle and search Bridge, adjust setup again under *Adjust last operation* (F9) like seen on screen

[image]
[image]

### For any version - SMOOTH surface

- smoothing surface - *Subdivision surface* Modifier, to sharp edges select them and set *Creas* (Shift+E) = 1, Set *Smooth* shading and under Object Data properties > Normals > enable Auto Smooth with Angle like 13 (in this case)

[image]

- to model hole (tube) you can anytime in a process a) delete face and use *Solidify Modifier* or b) select face Extrude (E) Scale (S) to make thickness of pipe and extrude again with move inside (before extrude change Transform Orientation > Normals)

[image]

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I was looking for! Much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You could perhaps use a Bridge Edge loop, then add some edge loops and scale those to get a crease-like effect.

Note that my hexagon already has a face in the images below; after executing Bridge Edge Loops this means that there'll now be internal faces in the model.
Remove any such faces before bridging (though you can probably also do it afterwards).
This also happens to the outside faces of the cylinder, you might want to remove those too.

Select the edges or vertices:
[image: Select the edges]

Find `Bridge Edge Loops` in the <kbd>space</kbd> search menu;
[image: Find 'bridge edge loops']

This'll create faces and edges between the selected edge loops.
[image: voila!]

---

To make the created edges and faces look they're pulled down by gravity, I've added some `Edge Loops` inbetween.
Since edge loops can only be practically applied to *quads* (faces with 4 vertices), I've added an intermediate circle with the same amount of vertices as my cylinder(24 in this case).

[image]

This is scaled to almost the size of the hexagon and then Bridge Edge Loops-ed to it. It's also bridged to the cylinder vertices like I mentioned before. 
The intermediate circle now connects to the hexagon using triangular faces, but it connects to the cylinder with quads, thus making Edge Loops possible to use.

[image]

Add some `Edge Loops` using <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>. Scroll the mouse wheel to change the number of cuts, and move it to determine where the cuts go. Click to apply the loops. Here I've scaled, rotated and moved the cuts to follow the form of the cylinder.

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot, I was able to replicate that and it looks much better than before. However, the lines connecting the hexagon with the tube are now straight whereas the look I try to achieve is more organic/curved as if gravity is pulling down on these lines. I hope that makes sense. Do you know how I could add that effect?

Comment: You can use edge loops with a little intermediate geometry, I've appended a how-to for that to my original answer.