# Problem with Boolean and combination from two objects

Tags: mesh, modifiers, objects, sculpting

- first I created a basemesh (I used the skin mod)
- next a separate head
- then append it and used boolean to glue them together
- discovered a problem

[image]

Both parts doesn't fit together well.
I guess the problem is that the head has lot more vertices than the body?!
Do you have an idea what to do?
Or is my way completely wrong to combine both objects?

Comment: Hi, welcome to Blender.se. Please only ask one question per post. Create as many posts as needed. What do you mean by "*contaminate both files*"? Do you mean "combine both objects" perhaps?

Comment: Yes. You are right - it should mean "combine both objects".
**edit it in the main text too.

Comment: Look at the methods in these answers: https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/159977/30849

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation. 
I have the feeling it doesn't fit to my problem bc i can't count my vertices. 
I discovered boolean works actually very well.The connection wasn't well bc i worked inaccurate. But still the same problem: The body parts are connected but there is still the "leftover". Do I have to delete it by hand? It seems inefficient :/

Comment: Do you internd to sculpt this result? Then you could use remeshing or dyntopo. If you want to uv unwrap/texture the object or rig it, you require good Topology with means adjusting the vertices manually.